# Give permission to select from system tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a database Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2.
A user called marie is defined, who can access tables on the main database; this works well.
Now, I would like marie to be able to perform this query:

```
SELECT resource_type,spid,login_time,status,hostname,program_name,nt_domain,nt_username,loginame
  FROM sys.dm_tran_locks dl
  JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp on dl.request_session_id = sp.spid
```

The tables involved are master tables; how do I give permission to marie to read from them?
I already tried to execute the following as dbo:

```
GRANT ALL on sys.dm_tran_locks TO marie
GRANT ALL on sys.sysprocesses TO marie
```

Still, when marie tries to perform the query above, the error is:

```
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also you should be using `sys.dm_exec_requests`, `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, etc. `sysprocesses` is a backward compatibility view and will be removed from the product at some point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

System views require a slightly elevated state to view, since they are instance wide.  You'll want to [`GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this:

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO marie;
```

Comment: Here is the link to the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, was looking for that.  :)  Link added to answer.

Comment: This isn't supported in Azure SQL db - how do I achieve the equivalent here?

Comment: Try `GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE`.

Comment: *Some* tables under `sys` can indeed be selected from with only select permissions of a single database, such as `sys.indexes`.