# AlwaysOn SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, jobs

We are running AlwaysOn on three replicas. The primary and first secondary are synchronous for failover purposes. The second secondary is a read-only asynchronous server for reporting. The only thing we don't have a good handle on is SQL Agent jobs on failover. I've seen a few solutions from others, but nothing I thought was really slick. How do you handle SQL Agent jobs on a secondary replica that is intended for failover?

Comment: Have you looked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45137/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-availability-groups ?

Comment: The golden rule: Do unto all servers that you do unto the primary. Making a new job, have it scripted and execute against the replica group through your CMS. Easy :)