# Scheduled jobs run twice after upgrade to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-agent, jobs

We recently upgraded from 2008 to 2012, with one of our applications running on an *active & passive* server (Always On). It has been running SQL Server Agent jobs twice at the exact same time.

We verified it wasn't the *passive* box, but we can't explain the trigger or reason(s) as to why its running twice.

Only one scheduled agent job appears. It is setup correctly to run 9:15 for Mon & Thu:

> Occurs every week on Monday, Thursday at 9:15:00 AM. Schedule will be used starting on 10/9/2014.

By disabling the scheduled job running the SP on the *passive* server the day before, only the "active" machine was scheduled and able to run. Only the *active* machine ran and the results were correct: one email was sent, it was completed and the records were not duplicated; **however**, when we run the job manually through the scheduler it fails since the server is passive.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you checked for more than one schedule on the agent job?

Answer (score -1):

I have working SQL to determine which machine is the `PRIMARY` or `SECONDARY` server and to use within the Stored Procedure scheduled to run on both machines:

```
select
    ars.role_desc,ag.name,ars.is_local
from sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
inner join sys.availability_groups ag
on ars.group_id = ag.group_id
```

**Note:** I was expecting the database to be identified but instead all the databases are placed into an "availability group (AG)".

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Results from the ACTIVE & PRIMARY machine 
note: whichever says "1" for is_local and "PRIMARY" indicated the active machine
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
IP:  100.1.1.1    
role_desc   name        is_local
PRIMARY     MasterSQL2AG    1
SECONDARY   MasterSQL2AG    0
```

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Results from the ACTIVE & PRIMARY machine 
note: whichever says "1" for is_local and "SECONDARY" indicated the PASSIVE machine 
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
IP:  100.10.10.10 
role_desc   name        is_local
SECONDARY   MasterSQL2AG    1
```

Another query providing more details and for the specific `DBID` is this:

```
DECLARE @description VARCHAR(25);
SELECT *
FROM   master.sys.DATABASES d
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states hars 
    ON d.replica_id = hars.replica_id
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('Customers')
```

Useful references, links and examples:

- [SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/143/alwayson-availability/)
- [SQL Server Agent Jobs and Availability Groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45137/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-availability-groups/45152#45152)