# How to add a step in all existing jobs in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs

```
IF (SELECT ars.role_desc
    FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
    INNER JOIN sys.availability_groups ag
    ON ars.group_id = ag.group_id
    AND ars.is_local = 1) <> 'PRIMARY'
BEGIN
   --We're on the secondary node, throw an error
   THROW 50001, 'Unable to execute job on secondary node',1
END
```

Set this step to continue with the next step on success, and to quit the job reporting success on a failure.

Can you  please explain how to add this step in all existing SQL server jobs?

Answer (score 7):

I have created a stored procedure which will add a new first step to any existing agent job.

It checks if running on the AG primary replica and quits with success otherwise:

```
use master
go

-- Adds a first step to specified job, which checks whether running on Primary replica

create procedure AddAGPrimaryCheckStepToAgentJob
    @jobname nvarchar(128)
as

set nocount on;

-- Do nothing if No AG groups defined
IF SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled') = 1
begin
    declare @jobid uniqueidentifier = (select sj.job_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj where sj.name = @jobname)

    if not exists(select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps where job_id = @jobid and step_name = 'Check If AG Primary' )
    begin
        -- Add new first step: on success go to next step, on failure quit reporting success
        exec msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep 
          @job_id = @jobid
        , @step_id = 1
        , @cmdexec_success_code = 0
        , @step_name = 'Check If AG Primary'
        , @on_success_action = 3  -- On success, go to Next Step
        , @on_success_step_id = 2
        , @on_fail_action = 1     -- On failure, Quit with Success  
        , @on_fail_step_id = 0
        , @retry_attempts = 0
        , @retry_interval = 0
        , @os_run_priority = 0
        , @subsystem = N'TSQL'
        , @command=N'IF (SELECT ars.role_desc
        FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
        JOIN sys.availability_groups ag ON ars.group_id = ag.group_id AND ars.is_local = 1) <> ''Primary''
    BEGIN
       -- Secondary node, throw an error
       raiserror (''Not the AG primary'', 2, 1)
    END'
        , @database_name=N'master'
        , @flags=0
    end
end
GO
```

Blog post is [here](https://mitchwheat.com/2018/05/29/sql-server-availability-groups-add-check-if-primary-step-to-existing-agent-jobs/).

Note: For SQL Server 2014 onwards you can use the builtin function [`sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica('dbname')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-hadr-is-primary-replica-transact-sql):

```
If sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica (@dbname) <> 1   
BEGIN 
    -- This is not the primary replica, exit without error. 
END 
-- This is the primary replica, continue to run the job...
```