# Sync Server Objects when having two or more Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, dbatools

Lets imagine that i have two servers/nodes with TWO availability groups `Group01` and `Group02`. I will need to ensure that the server objects are all the time recreated over the secondary replica.

If i have the `Group01` in one node as primary, and the `Group02` in the other node as primary, how will the sync of server objects be processed?

I was thinking of using [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) with one command line only:

```
Start-DbaMigration -Source $PrimaryInstance `
                   -Destination $SecondaryInstance ` 
                   -Exclude Databases
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server object are at the server level e.g. logins, jobs, etc. So you can just use [`Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup)

```
Syncs depdendent objects for availability groups. Such objects include:

SpConfigure
CustomErrors
Credentials
DatabaseMail
LinkedServers
Logins
LoginPermissions
SystemTriggers
DatabaseOwner
AgentCategory
AgentOperator
AgentAlert
AgentProxy
AgentSchedule
AgentJob
```

What you are using is a much bigger umbrella that folks use for migration from one server to another.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this ps function is scheduled to run as an agent job, and it will also sync this agent job then how do I ensure it only runs on primary?

Comment: you check before executing the function if it is a primary node or not .. e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66068/8783 will help you.