# What do you do with the SQL Agent Jobs when the HA environment switches between primary and secondary?

Tags: sql-server

What do you do with the SQL Agent Jobs when the HA environment switches between primary and secondary?
Do they just let the jobs on the secondary fail and create log entries when it can't access the database?

Comment: What kind of job are you specifically referring to?

Comment: Actually, when using HA (AG), I change all the job to add one step at the biggining that will check if the server is primary and will "stop" if not. That way, the jobs can have the same schedule on all nodes and a failover will not make it stop working

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher could you please share the step you add?

Comment: @KASQLDBA e.g backup,

Comment: I can see someone gave a full answer under https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45137/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-availability-groups