# SQL Server Agent Jobs and Availability group

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have two servers (Primary and Secondary), as well as an AG that keeps them in sync.

As we all know, System databases are not covered by the AG definition.

1.I require that all jobs on the primary server be in sync with those on the secondary server.

2.However, I just want the job to run on the primary, not the secondary. Is there anything I can do? Any sql code ? Kindly explain I am new to DBA.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to go through [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/commands/#AGs) It contains all the Powershell modules required to manage the **SQL Server Always On Availability Group**.

> 1.I require that all jobs on the primary server be in sync with those on the secondary server.

For Object syncing, check this package: [Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup) run periodically or schedule it.

> 2.However, I just want the job to run on the primary, not the secondary. Is there anything I can do? Any sql code ? Kindly explain I
> am new to DBA.

For running job only on the primary, at the beginning of the job, check whether is it primary or secondary, if primary, run the job.

[sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) dynamic management view will expose that information.

Check this [SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45152/21119) for the simple conditional logic implementation for the same.

Comment: Can I write sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states and invoke power shell together in the sql script? One is sql and other is ps.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to only running on the primary this is what I do

1. Create the first step in the agent job to check if the server is primary or secondary. This needs to be done in the context of the master database

`IF (SELECT ars.role_desc FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars JOIN sys.availability_groups ag ON ars.group_id = ag.group_id AND ars.is_local = 1) <> 'Primary' BEGIN -- Secondary node, throw an error raiserror ('Not the AG primary', 2, 1) END`

Then for the advanced steps set the following
On Success action: Go to the next step
On failure action: quit the job reporting success

Then you can have job the jobs active at the same time. On the secondary node the job will stop after step 1 and not report a failure and the primary node will go to step 2 and continue with the job